# What permissions should be on a plugin's folder in wordpress?

Tags: php, permissions, wordpress

When I extract a plugin's zip file into the `wp-content/plugins/the_extracted_plugin` directory, it shows the file permissions:

```
//Permissions I see for the newly installed plugin (installed manually via zip-file-extraction)
drwxr-sr-x
```

But when I look at the pre-installed plugin `akismet`, I see the permissions:

```
//Permissions of Wordpress-pre-installed plugin
drwxrws---
```

Which is the correct one? What would be the default permissions if I'd installed via the Wordpress Admin interface (i.e., in the browser, go to `plugins->add new`)?

What permissions do most plugins expect? Do they expect write permissions to their own folders?

Comment: I guess the downvotes are for not being a clear programming question. At first, it's a [su] issue, but it's really: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=plugin+file+permissions

Answer (score 1):

`755` Owned by `www-data:www-data` , or whatever your webserver-user:webserver-group are. 
If you want to be strict, and don't care for FTP or teams, `700` will be fine, as well.

that's : `drwxr-xr-x` or `drwx------` - if you want to be really strict.

They don't need write access to themselves, because the 7 will give the script that updates/uses them write access - that is, only the one user needs write access - and that user is the web-server, which the wp-admin acts as when logged in to the panel.

Comment: "They don't need write access to themselves" - this is incorrect. I made a test plugin that had the permissions `drwxr-sr-x` (which I believe is 2755) and it could not create a file in its own folder. (I had the plugin run a `put_file_contents` when called from the web admin interface)

Comment: Each plugin does not act as its own user. Thus, your issue there is going to be separate from permissions.

Comment: can you please explain that? Shouldn't it have the same permissions as anything else run from the web admin interface?

Comment: Your server runs as a user-- typically -  `www-data` or `nobody` -- neither wordpress nor its plugins get users for manipulating the file system - thus, "'they' don't need access to themselves" because "they" don't really exist on the filesystem as entities that you can grant permissions to - Thus, your permissions may've failed because of some ownership setup, where it needed to be `775` instead of `755`- in either case, the 5 can be a zero, and it shouldn't matter, since plugin files are never accessed by the "other" that number represents. Make sense?